# Definition of "equivalence classes"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata

I am studying finite state automata and learning how to prove a machine uses the minimum number of states. I have come across the Myhill-Nerode theorem and one of the corollaries states the following

> Corollary. For a deterministic finite automaton M, the minimum number
>   of states in any equivalent deterministic finite automaton is the same
>   as the number of equivalence classes of M's states.

My question is, what does "equivalence classes of M's states" mean?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two states are equivalent if they accept the same language. An equivalence class is therefore a set of states that all accept the same language (and no other state in the automaton does). In particular in a minimal autommaton, all states accept different languages, so each state is alone in its equivalence class.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Comment: For more on the notion of "equivalence class", see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class.